# Are the Halo Combat evolved servers for xbox360 active?

Tags: halo-anniversary

What I am asking is, since I am getting my xbox 360 re-installed, and I want to buy the halo combat edition game, but I don't know if there are people who still play that online multiplayer?

Comment: The XBox Version of Halo: Combat Evolved had no online multiplayer, just LAN multiplayer. Are you referring to the one released for XBOx 360, Halo: Combat Evolved Anniversary Edition?

Comment: ....Yes @Arkive

Comment: IIRC the multiplayer for this is shared with Halo: Reach so should still be plenty active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Oct 24, 2013, the multiplayer servers are still active and people are playing in them. I just tested it, and it took about 3 minutes for the matchmaking to find me a match.